# how to get a call log and select a number to display without using permissions in android

Tags: java, android

I have used the following code, which allows me to the visit call log without permission. but this only allows me to view but not to perform any actions with the intent.

```
1. Intent showCallLog = new Intent(); 
2. showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
3. showCallLog.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
4. startActivity(showCallLog);
```

when I use

> showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

It shows no content at all. The results look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhPH4.jpg).

Is there a way where I can all the content from the call logs and perform desired actions without actually having to use the permissions, since the  READ_CALL_LOG permission has now removed?

Ideally, if I could be able to use the intents to get the actual content in a form of a table (database) and then manipulate the data to get the relevant content. Is this attainable in a way somehow?